# joomla custom module

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

In **joomla 1.7** i am creating a custom module for registration. How I can check the user field

is empty or not? Which function is used to check user input field like **isset()** which is used

in php.

I want to check for **form is submitted** or not in joomla, according to that i want to display information.

Comment: did you mean if a user is logged in ?

Comment: i want to check user input like isset($_POST['name']) for access from JRequest::getVar().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_POST` && `$_GET`
or 
use the functions of jommla framework (recommended)
`JRequest::getString('INPUT_NAME','DEFAYLT_VALUE')`

check this link :
http://docs.joomla.org/JRequest/1.6

so to check use :

```
$Name = JRequest::getString('name_field',false);

if(false){
//NOT SET
}else{
//ISSET
}
```

Comment: @avesdon if you get solved the problem then please accept the answer to click on the check mark and +1